# ExtJS Set simple array to store

Tags: codeigniter, extjs

I have a codeigniter service that returns this:
**{data: ["CEDULA-1723822761.pdf", "CROQUIS-1723822761.pdf", "PENSION-1723822761.pdf"], success: "true"}**
And on my ExtJS App I'm trying to process it like this:

```
var responseData = opts.result.data;
    var documentos = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#docsTest")[0];
    documentos.setValue(responseData); //This is just to check that the data is correct
    var store = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
      fields:[
        {name: 'name'}//I'm pretty sure my problem is here
      ]
    });

    store.loadData(responseData);
    console.log('store:' + store);

    var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#FldDocumentos")[0];

    grid.setStore(store);
```

I want to show each one of the three results given by the service in a row in the grid but since the array doesn't specify a field name, the store just creates three empty objects. How can I correctly store each of the array strings in the store?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Array and store the data with name attribute. So when you add this to store, grid can display data correctly.

```
var responseData = opts.result.data;
var documentos = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#docsTest")[0];
documentos.setValue(responseData); //This is just to check that the data is correct
var store = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
  fields:[
    {name: 'name'}//I'm pretty sure my problem is here
  ]
});

var nameList = [];
for(var i = 0 ; i < responseData.length ; i++){
    nameList.push({ name = responseData[i]});
}

store.loadData(nameList);
console.log('store:' + store);

var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#FldDocumentos")[0];

grid.setStore(store);
```

Comment: You, sir, are great! It worked perfectly with some minor tweaks! var nameList = [] instead of {} and name : responseData[i] instead of name = responseData[i]